# 90’s off-brand cartoon movie about a man turned into a tree and princess who floods the kingdom with tears

Tags: story-identification, movie, cartoon

I’ve been looking for a while now for a 90s cartoon movie (musical) about a princess in love with a guy and someone turns him into a tree and I think she cries and floods the whole kingdom. I can almost remember the melody of the songs but not quite. I believe the princess had orange hair. It’s killing me, I’ve been at this for years

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Did you see this on TV or was it a recording (VHS or DVD)?  What language was it in?